# С# Как узнать поддерживается ли гибернация?

Tags: c#, sleep

Мое приложение должно переводить компьютер в спящий режим или в режим гибернации (на выбор пользователя). Проблема заключается в том, что я хочу при запуске приложения проверить, поддерживается ли в системе режим гибернации и включен ли этот режим в настройках. А как это сделать не могу найти. Ежели кто знает - прошу поделиться опытом.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41639864/5796587 похоже на то что вы ищете.

Comment: Да, это оно, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Мое приложение должно переводить компьютер в спящий режим или в режим гибернации (на выбор пользователя)

Опробуй код:

```
bool HibernationSuccess = Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Hibernate, true, true);
if (!HibernationSuccess)
{
    Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, true, true);
}
```

скорее всего этот код сработает как тебе нужно безо всяких доп.проверок. То есть опробует запустить гибернацию, если она недоступна то заслипает.

Просто слип же вызывается

```
Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, true, true);
```

---

По поводу проверки возможно ли сделать гибернацию без попытки гибернации... Найди какие записи в реестре отвечают за гибернацию и чекай их. Как один из вариантов.

Или проверяй наличие файла hiberfil.sys в корне всех дисков.

Comment: Этот код переводит в режим гибернации, а если не получилось то переводит в спящий режим. Именно так у меня и реализовано все. Но проверка на предмет того, возможна ли гибернация на компе, здесь отсутствует. А мне нужна именно она.
Насчет реестра - спасибо! Я что-то не догадался. Попробую вытащить данные из него.

Comment: С реестром все получилось, спасибо!
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power
нужно проверить ключ HibernateEnabled.